# Message Manager displays messages only as field decorators and not in header

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-pde

I am using the Eclipse `MessageManager` to provide error messages in case of invalid input. For example:

```
mmng.addMessage("textLength", "blah", null, IMessageProvider.ERROR, field);
```

I do this twice. Once inside an instance of `ModifyListener` and once just right after the creation of the `Text` field in order to validate input on load.

The `MessageManager` displays an error in the header of the page as well as next to the text field (decorator) when calling the `addMessage` method inside the `modifyEvent` method of an child instance of `ModifyListener`. However, when adding the message right after the creation of the text field, only a decorator will be displayed (no errors in the header saying that "n errors detected").

I am wondering why this happens. I tested this with the Eclipse [`ProductEditor`](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.pde.ui/blob/master/ui/org.eclipse.pde.ui/src/org/eclipse/pde/internal/ui/editor/product/ProductEditor.java) and there's actually a similar behavior. The errors won't appear in the header if you open a `.product` file that has on the first page an error (only the decorator will appear). However, when switching to other pages and then switching back to this particular page, the error in the header will appear. Unfortunately, this is not the case on my side. I would be satisfied if I could implement the same behavior, even though the best case would be to automatically display errors on both locations, in the header and next to the field as a decorator.

I also tried to solve this issue by calling the `update()` method of the `MessageManager` instance, but unfortunately, that did not solve the mystery.

By the way, I am using Eclipse Luna 2.

Answer (score 0):

I debugged the `MessageManager` class and noticed the following condition inside the `update` method:

```
if (form.getHead().getBounds().height == 0 || mergedList.isEmpty() || mergedList == null) {
            form.setMessage(null, IMessageProvider.NONE);
            return;
}
```

Besides that a NPE will be thrown when `mergedList` is null, this condition seems really strange to me. However, setting the height of head solved my problem:

```
form.getForm().getHead().setBounds(0, 0, 0, 1);
```